# How do you get the size of a non-interactive tmux pane?

Tags: size, tmux

I have several tmux panes running in a window that have been started with syntax like:

```
tmux split-window -h -l {dynamic value} tail -f somefile.txt
tmux split-window -v -l {dynamic value} tail -f someotherfile.txt
tmux split-window -h -l {dynamic value} nc -l -p {random port}
```

As I use this script to create new panes and I need to update an array in my script with the sizes of each "window" (pane).

If the tmux panes contained interactive shells, I could just run tput cols and tput rows in them to get the size. I checked the tmux man page, but didn't see the commands I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know a pane’s id (e.g. `%24`) or its name (e.g. `session_name:win_idx.pane_idx`; see `target-pane` in the man page), then you can use `display-message -p` to query the dimensions:

```
tmux display-message -pt "$pane" -F '#{pane_width}x#{pane_height}'
```

If you do not already have a way to name to panes, then you can collect the pane ids as you split them off by using the `-P` option along with the `-F` option:

```
pane_a=$(tmux split-window -PF '#{pane_id}' -hl "$dynamic_value" 'tail -f somefile.txt')
⋮ # create other panes
pane_a_width=$(tmux display-message -pt "$pane_a" -F '#{pane_width}')
```

---

If you want to know about all the panes in a window, then you can use `list-panes` with the window’s id (e.g. `@5`) or name (e.g. `session_name.win_idx`; see `target-window` in the man page):

```
tmux list-panes -t "$window" -F '#{pane_id} #{pane_width}x#{pane_height} #{session_name}:#{window_index}.#{pane_index}'
```

---

Some of these options and format specifiers are not available on old versions of *tmux*, but there are usually workarounds (depending on just how old your version is).